# UPDATE in MySQL / Python with multiple JOIN

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

First batch of the question was deemed too similar to another post (It wasn't) and closed... So here I am with another try, this time better worded I hope.

Some background: Here we have the relationships.
A security (coin) + a currency (basecoin) form a pair.
A pair and a broker form an asset (I consider each broker/pair as a specific asset)

[image]

I also have a forex table where I store the live currency exchange rates.

In my trade history table (history_price) I have a column with a lot of NULL (the EUR volumes) with I calculate from the Volume. All I want to do is fill it and for that I have to (for each NULL line):

Here is how I have segmented my query:

## 1- Find currency

```
SELECT `history_price`.`param_basecoin`.`Symbol` 
FROM `history_price`.`param_asset` 
INNER JOIN `param_pair` ON `history_price`.`param_asset`.`id_pair` = `history_price`.`param_pair`.`pair_id` 
INNER JOIN `history_price`.`param_basecoin` ON `history_price`.`param_pair`.`Coin2_id` = `history_price`.`param_basecoin`.`basecoin_id` 
WHERE `history_price`.`param_asset`.`Ticker` LIKE '???'
```

## 2- Find exchange rate

```
SELECT `Rate` 
FROM `history_price`.`param_forex` 
WHERE `Coin` LIKE '???' AND `Basecoin` LIKE 'EUR'
```

## 3- update EUR column

```
UPDATE `history_price` 
SET `history_price`.`eur_v` = (`history_price`.`Basecoin_v` * ???) 
WHERE `history_price`.`eur_v` IS NULL
```

## 4- insert 2 into 3

```
UPDATE `history_price` 
SET `history_price`.`eur_v` = (`history_price`.`Basecoin_v` * (SELECT `Rate` FROM `history_price`.`param_forex` WHERE `Coin` LIKE '???' AND `Basecoin` LIKE 'EUR')) 
WHERE `history_price`.`eur_v` IS NULL
```

## 5- insert 1 into 4

```
UPDATE `history_price` 
SET `history_price`.`eur_v` = (`history_price`.`Basecoin_v` * (
    SELECT `Rate` 
    FROM `history_price`.`param_forex` 
    WHERE `Coin` LIKE (
        SELECT `history_price`.`param_basecoin`.`Symbol` 
        FROM `history_price`.`param_asset` 
        INNER JOIN `param_pair` ON `history_price`.`param_asset`.`id_pair` = `history_price`.`param_pair`.`pair_id` 
        INNER JOIN `history_price`.`param_basecoin` ON `history_price`.`param_pair`.`Coin2_id` = `history_price`.`param_basecoin`.`basecoin_id` 
        WHERE `history_price`.`param_asset`.`Ticker` LIKE `history_price`.`Ticker`
        ) 
        AND `Basecoin` LIKE 'EUR'
        )
    ) 
WHERE `history_price`.`eur_v` IS NULL;
```

It does work, but it is so slow...
Is there a way to optimise this and make it faster?

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=`? You don't have wildcard patterns in `history_price.Ticker`, do you?

Comment: No particular reason, I use them interchangeably. Am I missing out of something by using LIKE?

Comment: `LIKE` does pattern matching, it may be slower than `=`, which just does an exact match.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference when you're comparing with a literal like `EUR`, since the parser can see that there's no wildcard and optimize it. But if you're comparing with dynamic values, it doesn't know that they're all ordinary strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` rather than a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE history_price AS hp
JOIN param_asset AS pa ON pa.Ticker = hp.Ticker
JOIN param_pair AS pp ON pp.id_pair = pa.id_pair
JOIN param_basecoin AS pb ON pb.basecoin_id = pp.Coin2_id
JOIN param_forex AS pf ON pf.Coin = pb.Symbol
SET hp.eur_v = hp.Basecoin_v * pf.Rate
WHERE pf.Basecoin = 'EUR' AND hp.eur_v IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks @Barmar, I need to brush up my JOIN skills. I have another question, but this time I think I have no choice but to use a correlated subquery, if you care to talk a quick look.

Comment: Correlated subqueries can almost always be replaced with joins. Are you sure this one isn't working?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and the desired results in the question? See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support for how to post a table in markdown.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. The JOIN did work in this case. The one I am struggling to solve is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76194196/first-value-and-last-value-fail-in-mysql-query?noredirect=1#comment134369888_76194196