# FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE fail in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a table (`Hist_price`) with `Time`, `Price` and `Ticker`. Basically a table of historical prices for a list of assets (`Ticker`)

I want to calculate my own candle sticks. First method tried (and failed) was:

```
   SELECT `Ticker`,
   FIRST_VALUE(`Price`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Ticker` ORDER BY `Time` ) AS open_p,
   MIN(`Price`) AS min_price,
   MAX(`Price`) AS max_price,
   LAST_VALUE(`Price`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Ticker`ORDER BY `Time` ) AS close_p
   FROM `Hist_price`
   WHERE `Time` >= 1683212332325 AND `Time` < 2683222332325
   GROUP BY `Ticker`;
```

But it did not work. The FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE returned the same value... Basically FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE did not work as I thought they did....

second try is to do it as advised with (I will find the open and close by looking through their trade_id)

```
   SELECT `Ticker`,
   MIN(`trade_ID`) AS first_trade,
   MIN(`Price`) AS min_price,
   MAX(`Price`) AS max_price,
   MAX(`trade_ID`) AS last_trade,
   (SELECT `Price` FROM `Hist_price` WHERE  `trade_ID` = first_trade) AS open_price,
   (SELECT `Price` FROM `Hist_price` WHERE  `trade_ID` = last_trade) AS close_price
   FROM `Hist_price`
   WHERE `Time` >= 1683469229380 AND `Time` < 1683469349380
   GROUP BY `Ticker`;
```

But I seem to struggle with that correlated subquery :

#1247 - Reference 'first_trade' not supported (reference to group function)

#1247 - Reference 'last_trade' not supported (reference to group function)

Any help , please? I am almost there...

Comment: You're not aggregating `Price` and you're not grouping by it either.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see where that would fit in my query. I must be lissing somtehing. PLease be more specific

Comment: [This question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54357532/1191247) explain why your use of `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE` does not function as you think it does. Just use a normal GROUP BY query to get min/max time and price per ticker, for the given time range, and then correlated sub-queries in the SELECT list to retrieve the first and last price values.

Comment: thank you @user1191247. That help me stop wasting time on a dead end. I have edited the question. Maybe you can give me the last push pover the finish line?

Comment: thank you @user1191247 but I think I must be missing a subtility in the code... I have edited the question with more info. Anything I might need to look at in your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the calculation of the first and last trades in a CTE. Join that with the `Hist_price` table twice to get the first and last prices.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT `Ticker`,
       MIN(`trade_ID`) AS first_trade,
       MIN(`Price`) AS min_price,
       MAX(`Price`) AS max_price,
       MAX(`trade_ID`) AS last_trade
    FROM `Hist_price`
    WHERE `Time` >= 1683469229380 AND `Time` < 1683469349380
    GROUP BY Ticker
)

SELECT cte.*, h1.price AS open_price, h2.price AS close_price
FROM cte
JOIN Hist_price AS h1 ON h1.trade_id = cte.first_trade
JOIN Hist_price AS h2 on h2.trade_id = cte.last_trade;
```

Comment: Right on both counts

Comment: thank you Barmar.  It does look so easy once it's infront of your eyes...

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the window functions only as follows :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT `Ticker`,
  ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by `Ticker` order by `Time` desc) as rn,
  FIRST_VALUE(`Price`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Ticker` ORDER BY `Time` ) AS open_p,
  MIN(`Price`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Ticker` ORDER BY `Time` ) AS min_price,
  MAX(`Price`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Ticker` ORDER BY `Time` ) AS max_price,
  LAST_VALUE(`Price`) OVER(PARTITION BY `Ticker`ORDER BY `Time` ) AS close_p
  FROM `Hist_price`
  WHERE `Time` >= 1683212332325 AND `Time` < 2683222332325
)
select *
from cte
where rn=1
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/0D3vBxHV)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does work. But it's slow and resources intensive. It seems wastefull to be calculating hundreds (thousands in my case) of lines to be taking only 1 after...
Any other idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the alias to an aggregate value as a reference in a subquery in the SELECT list but you can use the aggregate function directly -

```sql
SELECT
    Ticker,
    (SELECT Price FROM Hist_price WHERE trade_ID = MIN(hp.trade_ID)) AS open_price,
    MIN(Price) AS min_price,
    MAX(Price) AS max_price,
    (SELECT Price FROM Hist_price WHERE trade_ID = MAX(hp.trade_ID)) AS close_price
FROM Hist_price hp
WHERE Time >= 1683469229380 AND Time < 1683469349380
GROUP BY Ticker;
```